# How to (accidentally) write into the global context (namespace) with coffeescript?

Tags: namespaces, coffeescript, global

I accidentally stumbled over the following code that actually modified the global namespace:
I though this is not possible?

The following code writes three variables into the global namespace ([try it](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3athis.my_global1%3D1%0A%40my_global2%3D2%0Af%3D%20-%3E%20%40my_global3%3D3%0Af%28%29)):

```
this.my_global1=1
@my_global2=2
f= -> @my_global3=3
f()
```

If you now replace the above code with this in the cofeescript try page

```
alert("#{[my_global1,my_global2,my_global3]}")
```

you will see an alert with

```
1,2,3
```

This means the statements above modify the global context!

It took me many hours to figure out what was going wrong with my code, because I thought coffeescript protects me form accidental changes of the global environment!

Comment: `this` is `window`, so the code is doing exactly what you tell it to do.

Comment: indeed but this is not clear form the code

Comment: There's no way for CoffeeScript to know what `this` is in every scope. That's a bit beyond the scope of the language.

Comment: true. But I have not seen any warnings about that. I realised that some code modified global variables but searching for global namespace did not reveal that ```f= -> this.$=3``` modifies the global $ (if running in a browser)

Comment: That's just how JavaScript works in non-strict mode. `this` must be an object, so it defaults to `window`. If you used strict mode, `this` would be `undefined`.

Comment: How to use strict mode? Maybe that's the answer to prevent this type of error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoffeeScript can't prevent you from doing this, but JavaScript can. Use strict mode:

```
do ->
  "use strict"

  this.$ = 3
```

In non-strict mode, `this` defaults to `window` if it isn't specified when the function is called. In strict mode, `this` becomes `undefined`, which will throw an error if you try to assign properties to it:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property '$' of undefined
```

Comment: To make it clear: the rest of the code has to be indented if you put this in front of your script.

Comment: @Michael_Scharf: The `do ->` is just a self-executing anonymous function (`(function() {...})()`). You don't really need it.

Comment: @Blender The preferred term is IIFE (http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Comment: @AaronDufour: Thanks, I wasn't aware that they weren't equivalent.

Comment: @Blender They are used basically interchangeably, but "self-executing anonymous function" is misleading and/or imprecise - by no means does the function "execute itself".  Only recursive functions execute themselves.